# Code Coverage issue in angular 8 with function properties

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

[image: Code Coverage error with Angular 8 project]

Can anyone suggest unit test case for Jasmine to resolve this code coverage issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to create a `describe` block as below:

   ```
   it('should create with necessary variables', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
     component.Items[0].getInfo();
     expect(component.isIndian).toBeTruthy();
     // and so on....
   });
   ```
2. You are setting `this.isIndian` as `false` at line 19 and then `true` at line 21. Please correct it accordingly.

In case you want to explore best practices, you can take a look at collection of articles [in this article](https://medium.com/@shashankvivek.7/say-hi-to-jasmine-karma-in-angular-intro-d728d669a1c7).

Comment: I agree the code supplied as an image is generally not optimal. However in this case I think the OP wanted to illustrate the red code rendering, which I guess indicates non-covered code.

Comment: @halfer
Thanks a lot. Sure I'll change accordingly that isIndian property. By mistake property was un-commented.

Comment: @Shashank Vivek

Thank you very much.